# Identify this plaster cornice coving from the UK

Tags: plaster, carpentry

I am in the UK and need to replace some coving, and am not sure how to track it down. It's probably 20 years old now, but I'm not sure if it's a generic size?

Thanks!

[image: Partial label]

[image: Profile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out (after pulling.it all down) it is Gyproc, readily available from selco
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pretty generic coving to me.

If you're not sure if it's a generic size... then find out! Easiest way to check that is to walk into your local DIY store (B&Q, Wickes, whatever) with that small bit and check to see if they stock something similar.

Comment: Yeah, guess I'm going to be receiving 25m of coving  instead of 4 :/ can't find anything like it

Comment: Yep, sounds like custom made-to-match is your only option then. Sorry.